# LibGDX Background Image in FitViewport

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So, I'm using LibGDX for my upcoming App.

I use a FitViewport to ensure the 16:9 aspect ratio.
So players with other aspect ratios than 16:9 will have black bars at sites.

**What is the best way, to draw a screen filling background image, that also covers the area, where the black bars would be?**

```
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(WIDTH, HEIGHT, camera);
    viewport.apply();
    camera.position.set(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, 0);
    camera.update();
```

Thats how I set up my camera/viewport currently.

I then draw stuff on it with a SpriteBatch.

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

That's how I currently at least change the color of the black bars, to any RGB color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the best idea is to create a second stage and it's own `Viewport` only for background purposes. This second `Viewport` should not be **FillViewport** - it will strech your graphics from my experience. I think **ExtendViewport** is better in this case.

So how should it look:

```
    Stage stage, backStage;
    FitViewport viewport;
    ExtendViewport backViewport;

    ...

    stage = new Stage(); //this is your normal stage you have now
    stage.setViewport( yourFitViewport ); //here you are assingning fit viewport

    backViewport = new ExtendViewport( screenWidth, screenHeight );

    backStage = new Stage();
    backStage.setViewport( backViewport ); 

    ...
    //now add to backStage your background Image

    backStage.addActor( yourBackground );
```

Now just handle new stage in the render method.

```
    backStage.act();
    stage.act();

    backStage.draw(); //backStage first - we want it under stage
    stage.draw();
```

And update new `Viewport` in update or render like your old one. That's all.

Read more about `Viewports` here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: Neither a Texture not a Sprite is addable to a stage as actor.
I was still able to do it with the ExtendViewport though, thanks.

Comment: yup but **new Image( Texture texture );** is

Comment: @m.antkowicz any idea why `This second Viewport should not be FillViewport `?

Comment: @best wishes - because fill viewport is stretching graphics and because different displays have different ratio the result can be a tragedy :)