# Need help scaling screen in LibGDX/Box2d

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, viewport, scaling

I've been creating a simple game for android/desktop using the libGDX framework. It's about done, but I've had a lot of trouble getting it to scale to different screen ratios. I am currently using a FitViewport, which works fine for keeping my desired screen ratio, but I'd like to make it so that the black bars on the top and bottom are colored for the sky and ground respectively. I've also tried not using a viewport at all, then adding the colors using a ShapeRenderer, but it just stretches all of the art to fit the screen, doesn't use my desired screen ratio, and ignores the ShapeRenderer shapes.

Here's my GameRenderer class's constructor code:

```
public GameRenderer (GameWorld gameWorld) {
    this.gameWorld = gameWorld;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, V_WIDTH / PPM, V_HEIGHT / PPM);

    uiCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
    uiCamera.setToOrtho(false, V_WIDTH, V_HEIGHT);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    viewport = new FitViewport(V_WIDTH / PPM, V_HEIGHT / PPM, camera);
    viewport.apply();

    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    frog = gameWorld.getFrog();
    jumpRope = gameWorld.getJumpRope();

    score = gameWorld.getScore() + "";
    highScore = AssetLoader.getHighScore() + "";
}
```

And here is the render() method:

```
    public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    score = gameWorld.getScore() + "";
    highScore = AssetLoader.getHighScore() + "";

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(AssetLoader.background, 0, 0, 236 / PPM, 300 / PPM);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(uiCamera.combined);
    if (gameWorld.isReady() || gameWorld.isTitleScreen() ) {
        AssetLoader.shadow.getData().setScale(0.4f, 0.4f);
        AssetLoader.shadow.draw(batch, "Tap to start!", 23, V_HEIGHT - 60);

        AssetLoader.font.getData().setScale(0.4f, 0.4f);
        AssetLoader.font.draw(batch, "Tap to start!", 22, V_HEIGHT - 61);
    } else {
        if (gameWorld.isGameOver()) {
            AssetLoader.shadow.getData().setScale(0.4f, 0.4f);
            AssetLoader.shadow.draw(batch, "Game Over", 40, V_HEIGHT - 60);

            AssetLoader.font.getData().setScale(0.4f, 0.4f);
            AssetLoader.font.draw(batch, "Game Over", 39, V_HEIGHT - 61);

            AssetLoader.shadow.draw(batch, "High Score: " + highScore, 15, V_HEIGHT - 90);
            AssetLoader.font.draw(batch, "High Score: " + highScore, 14, V_HEIGHT - 91);
        } else {
            AssetLoader.shadow.getData().setScale(0.55f, 0.55f);
            AssetLoader.shadow.draw(batch, score, (V_WIDTH / 2) - (8 * score.length()), V_HEIGHT / 1.25f);

            AssetLoader.font.getData().setScale(0.55f, 0.55f);
            AssetLoader.font.draw(batch, score, (V_WIDTH / 2) - (8 * score.length()) - 1, V_HEIGHT / 1.25f - 1);
        }
    }

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    if (jumpRope.getJumpRopeBehindFrog()) {
        jumpRope.draw(batch);
    }

    if (gameWorld.getFrog().getY() > -60 / PPM) {
        frog.draw(batch);
    }

    if (!jumpRope.getJumpRopeBehindFrog()) {
        jumpRope.draw(batch);
    }

    batch.end();

    debugRenderer.render(gameWorld.getWorld(), camera.combined);

    gameWorld.getWorld().step(1/60f, 6, 2);
}
```

I use the main OrthographicCamera camera for all of my gameplay and Box2D stuff, and I use the uiCamera for all of the UI, as the name implies. Any and all help is appreciated!

After trying to add a backStage:

```
    public GameRenderer (GameWorld gameWorld) {
    this.gameWorld = gameWorld;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, V_WIDTH / PPM, V_HEIGHT / PPM);

    uiCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
    uiCamera.setToOrtho(false, V_WIDTH, V_HEIGHT);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    // Test code
    backViewport = new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    backStage = new Stage();
    backStage.setViewport(backViewport);
    //

    viewport = new FitViewport(V_WIDTH / PPM, V_HEIGHT / PPM, camera);
    viewport.apply();

    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    frog = gameWorld.getFrog();
    jumpRope = gameWorld.getJumpRope();

    score = gameWorld.getScore() + "";
    highScore = AssetLoader.getHighScore() + "";

    // Test code
    backStage.addActor(new Image(AssetLoader.backgroundColor));
}

public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    score = gameWorld.getScore() + "";
    highScore = AssetLoader.getHighScore() + "";

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(AssetLoader.background, 0, 0, 236 / PPM, 300 / PPM);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(uiCamera.combined);
    if (gameWorld.isReady() || gameWorld.isTitleScreen() ) {
        AssetLoader.shadow.getData().setScale(0.4f, 0.4f);
        AssetLoader.shadow.draw(batch, "Tap to start!", 23, V_HEIGHT - 60);

        AssetLoader.font.getData().setScale(0.4f, 0.4f);
        AssetLoader.font.draw(batch, "Tap to start!", 22, V_HEIGHT - 61);
    } else {
        if (gameWorld.isGameOver()) {
            AssetLoader.shadow.getData().setScale(0.4f, 0.4f);
            AssetLoader.shadow.draw(batch, "Game Over", 40, V_HEIGHT - 60);

            AssetLoader.font.getData().setScale(0.4f, 0.4f);
            AssetLoader.font.draw(batch, "Game Over", 39, V_HEIGHT - 61);

            AssetLoader.shadow.draw(batch, "High Score: " + highScore, 15, V_HEIGHT - 90);
            AssetLoader.font.draw(batch, "High Score: " + highScore, 14, V_HEIGHT - 91);
        } else {
            AssetLoader.shadow.getData().setScale(0.55f, 0.55f);
            AssetLoader.shadow.draw(batch, score, (V_WIDTH / 2) - (8 * score.length()), V_HEIGHT / 1.25f);

            AssetLoader.font.getData().setScale(0.55f, 0.55f);
            AssetLoader.font.draw(batch, score, (V_WIDTH / 2) - (8 * score.length()) - 1, V_HEIGHT / 1.25f - 1);
        }
    }

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    if (jumpRope.getJumpRopeBehindFrog()) {
        jumpRope.draw(batch);
    }

    if (gameWorld.getFrog().getY() > -60 / PPM) {
        frog.draw(batch);
    }

    if (!jumpRope.getJumpRopeBehindFrog()) {
        jumpRope.draw(batch);
    }

    batch.end();

    // I put this in front of everything so that I could see what it's doing
    backStage.act();
    backStage.draw();
    //

    debugRenderer.render(gameWorld.getWorld(), camera.combined);

    gameWorld.getWorld().step(1/60f, 6, 2);
}

public void resize (int width, int height) {
    backViewport.update(width, height);
    viewport.update(width, height);
}
```

Comment: I believe that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552831/libgdx-background-image-in-fitviewport) may help.

Comment: Nope, I add what I want in the background to the backStage, but it won't go past the main FitViewport, nor will it scale to the proper size, even when I use Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / getHeight()

Comment: I see. Are you using a seperate `ExtendViewport` for the `backStage` like the question suggested?

Comment: Yep! It's definitely possible I messed it up, I can edit my post to show what I added if you think that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from [Libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports#multiple-viewports):

> **Multiple viewports**
>
> When using multiple viewports that have different screen sizes (or you use other code that sets glViewport), you will need to apply the viewport before drawing so the glViewport is set for that viewport.
>
> ```
> viewport1.apply();
> // draw
> viewport2.apply();
> // draw
> ```
>
> When using multiple Stages:
>
> ```
> stage1.getViewport().apply();
> stage1.draw();
> stage2.getViewport().apply();
> stage2.draw();
> ```

**Upd**. Couple of notes, unrelated to your question:

- Using static references on assets (like `AssetLoader.background` in your code) is usually considered as a bad practice. For example, read these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901466/6836125, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44357810/6836125
- SpriteBatches are heavy objects, so it's better to have only one `SpriteBatch` instance and to share it:

  `backStage = new Stage(backViewport, batch);`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks so much! I ended up just removing `backStage` completely and using `ShapeRenderer` instead, since I just wanted color as opposed to a `TextureRegion`. Either way, applying the proper `Viewport` before drawing was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Also, thanks for the notes, I decided to make my AssetLoader non-static and just passed it along from the main class instead. It's those smaller things that I need to keep an eye on!